# Why are memory fences required in Petersons Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing

```cpp
bool in_critical[2] = {false,false}; 
int turn;

enter(int me, int other) {
  (S1:) in_critical[me] = true;
  (S2:) turn = other;

  while(in_critical[other] && (turn == other)) ;
}

exit(int me) {
  in_critical[me] = false;
}
```

above a simple implementation of the peterson's algorithm.

In different online resources it states that a memory fence is required before the `while(..)` in order to prevent issues from `out-of-order execution`. So the order of `S1 and S2` is not exchanged.

But I can't spot the exact constellation where this would be an issue. So my question is either: In which exact reordering could an issue occurs ?

Or if this is more of a coherence issues. So maybe `in_critical[me]` will never be written out and both processors may just use it internally (cpu register never written to cache). In that case both processors would get into the critical section.
And the memory fence would force to make `in_critical[me]` visible.

Comment: I'm sure someone with a better understanding will pick even more examples but imagine `enter(...); do(); exit(...);`. Compiler will probably inline them. Now you have `in_critical[me] = true` at the beginning and and `in_critical[me] = false` at the end and no reason why the CPU can't reorder them as it pleases.

Comment: I think the issue with the reordering is espacially in `S1 and S2`. At least from literature I've seen.

So if two threads call the enter method at the exact time. The reordering of S1 and S2 will result in both threads entering the critical region

Comment: I do not think there is any difference when reordering S1 and S2 (S2 uses values  unrelated to S1 then it does not matter if you move S2 before S1). The problem (or one of) is when _something else_ (code from `exit()`) is moved before or after those two instructions (or the opposite...S1 is moved after `while`). Just try: swap them and the algorithm is still functional. Now move `in_critical[me] = false` before `while` and it does not work any more. That's why you need a memory barrier before `while` (and possibly after `exit()` if cache coherency is not guaranteed).

Comment: First of all, if you are talking about C, `in_critical` and `turn` should both be `volatile` to prevent compiler optimizations. This would prevent compiler reordering and compiler loop optimization (as you can [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/q14az8), note the `.L3 jmp .L3` infinite loop). Swapping S1 and S2 also shouldn't be an issue, meaning that you should place the fence before the `while` loop. **(update)** Actually, as David wrote, there is a race condition which arises if S1 and S2 are swapped, so there *should* be a fence between them too.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti did you read the answer markes as correct ? As this is a example how it can be broken without a fence (exactly what I was looking for)

Comment: You're right, let me rephrase better: no that example does not describe the entire problem. A memory barrier does not stop the compiler to reorder (if in the mood, and yes the compiler) those instructions. Reordering is just the tip: _changes_ could be propagated out of order (even when instructions are not). Not to mention atomic access.

Comment: It's true that the compiler still may reorder S1 and S2 from my understanding. But the barrier does ensure that changes are propagated so cache coherency can invalidate / update incorrect values in other caches.

(If I understand correctly)

Comment: That's true but changes might be propagated before the barrier. Compiler might decide to keep S1 in a register and S2 not. If another thread has a chance to run up to `while` before P0 reaches its barrier then you've got same result. Really not my field but I think that an implementation (for modern CPUs) will be way more complicate (and it will involve atomic read/write and barriers for each of those read/write).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the system can reorder S1 and S2. Then it's possible to get both processes into a critical section at the same time.

P0 starts by setting `turn = 1` (reordered). P1 goes next, setting `in_critical[1] = true` and `turn = 0`, then reads `false` from `in_critical[0]` in while condition and enters the critical section. Now P0 has a turn, writing `in_critical[0] = true` (reordered), reading `true` from `in_critical[1]` but `0` from `turn`, so P0 also enters the critical section.

Comment: Thanks that is what is was looking for